# Multiple virtualhosts for two python sites, one dominates

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to get an apache server configured on a Mac server to serve both a Web2Py app and a Flask application. This has become a mild nightmare. I would like the users to be able to go to the following urls

`http:/my.domain.com/`  - Web2py site

`http:/my.domain.com/suburl` - Flask site

Unfortunately, when I visit the suburl, it always takes me to the Web2py site (which then freaks out because there's no application named suburl). Here is my `.conf` file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
# Flask Site
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName my.domain.com/suburl
   WSGIDaemonProcess flask-suburl user=_www group=_www
   WSGIProcessGroup flask-suburl
   WSGIScriptAlias /suburl /Users/myname/suburl/app.wsgi
   <Directory /Users/myname/suburl>
      WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# Web2py Site
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName my.domain.com
   WSGIDaemonProcess web2py-main user=_www group=_www
   WSGIProcessGroup web2py-main
   WSGIScriptAlias / /Users/myname/web2py/wsgihandler.py
   <Directory /Users/myname/web2py>
      AllowOverride None
      Order Allow,Deny
      Deny from all
      <Files wsgihandler.py>
         Allow from all
      </Files>
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Reordering the two VirtualHost definitions doesn't do anything. Removing the Web2py site allows me to access the Flask site.

I'd rather not combine them into a single VirtualHost, because that causes problems with the two applications sharing the same Python interpreter and certain C extensions are apparently flipping out.

I've changed the domain and a few other names to hide protected information. I'm also excluding a few AliasMatch commands that handle serving the static subfolders. There's also another VirtualHost for the SSH server on port 443, but I didn't include it because I expect that to not affect things.

So how on earth do I make it so I can visit both sites, instead of the Web2py site swallowing everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming here, I've solved my problem. It was a simple mistake, and I could have sworn I had tried this before.

In the configuration for the Flask site, I should have done:

```
ServerName my.domain.com
...
WSGIScriptAlias /suburl /Users/myname/suburl/app.wsgi
```

Notice that the ServerName no longer has `/suburl` at the end of it. Instead, make sure that that has been added to the first argument of WSGIScriptAlias. The reasoning becomes clear when you look at [the documentation for WSGIScriptAlias](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIScriptAlias); the first argument is the URL-path that is being accessed. ServerName must remain pure.